Location that issued formal paper
Which one is more common, idiomatical (those are GPT's suggestions)?


place of issue
place of issuance
issuance location


It refers to the location where you're issued some formal paper, such as id. For example, in Russian passports there's a field called "место выдачи"

US and Canadian passports both use "Authority" for this information, which covers not only the office where you might receive the document, but also the office that might have mailed the document to you at your home.

@CanadianYankee I guess that word may be a bit overloaded, hence confusing. I need to name a variable in code

IssuingAuthority perhaps? https://www.helpside.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Issuing-Authories-for-I-9-Documents-Helpside.pdf

Place of issue sounds much the most idiomatic to me.
The iWeb corpus has 7 instances of "issuance location", 70 of "place of issuance", and 144 of "place of issue".
The NOW corpus has similar ratios, though smaller numbers.
